# database row quantity max insert to proceeding Row

Tags: mysql, sql

Hello i have this scenario currently i have 3 default sections. **A** , **B** and **C**,
What I'm trying to do is every time i add a new student it should check if the **section** is  full if so it should progress to the next section. eg. when **A** is full the student is automatically inserted to **B** same goes to **B** and **C**. So far my **tbl_section** is structured like this:

```
     tbl_section:
     section_id
     section_name
     school_year
     adviser_id
     year_level
```

Will this structure suffice? do i need to add a field for example quantity on **tbl_secion**? so that everytime i add a new student to that **section** it would increase the quantity. Would appreciate any help. On how can i perform this.

EDIT: or should i link my **SELECT** with my **tbl_students** to check how many are in a **section**?

Comment: Wich RDBMS are you using, MS SQL Server, MySQL, Postgre, Oracle? it helps to create a usefull query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you know if a section is full?  You need a capacity as well.

You also need another table, SectionStudent, that tells you the assignment between students and section.

With this information you can write a query to determine the first "non-full" section.  Here is one way:

```
select s.Section
from section s join
     SectionStudent ss
     on s.section_id = ss.section_id
group by Section
having count(*) < max(s.capacity)
```

Comment: Thanks, Am i able to do this with only using **tbl_section** ?

Comment: You don't want to.  You would have to update a count for the current number of students.  And then decrement, if a student drops out or changes sections.  You really want to keep track of which students are where.